# Connect Nginx and Varnish 6 via Unix Domain Socket not working

Tags: nginx, varnish, unix-socket

I'm using Nginx as SSL endpoint in front of Varnish 6 on the same machine. This works well when using a TCP port. Since Varnish 6 supports listening on Unix Domain sockets I changed my configuration to use sockets:

- varnishd started with option: `-a /var/run/varnish.sock,PROXY,user=varnish,group=varnish,mode=666` (previously it was -a :8080)
- in Nginx configuration, I changed `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;` to `proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/varnish.sock;`

Restart Nginx and Varnish, no errors are shown. The socket file /var/run/varnish.sock is created and is world writeable (I know, I know... I just wanted to get it running). Netstat says that varnishd is listening to /var/run/varnish.sock.

But it's not working, any web request to nginx returns "502 Bad Gateway".

The Nginx error log says "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream".

Varnishlog shows entries like the following for every request:

```
*   << Session  >> 65578
-   Begin          sess 0 PROXY
-   SessOpen       0.0.0.0 0 a0 0.0.0.0 0 1557937009.691636 21
-   SessClose      RX_JUNK 0.000
-   End
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Varnish is varnish-6.0.3 revision 7d1ded3aa033a018317dbafc61587026ea2ef8a3,
Nginx is nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu),
Running on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Varnish listening with PROXY protocol, but NGINX is talking regular HTTP protocol to it. Thus it fails.

To be precise, `-a /var/run/varnish.sock,PROXY,user=varnish,group=varnish,mode=666` means that Varnish listens on UDS socket *only* accepting PROXY protocol. There is no magical switch to have it accept both regular HTTP and PROXY protocols.

In a perfect world, you would have a way for NGINX to forward (talk) PROXY protocol to Varnish. But you can't do this with `proxy_pass` within `http {}` context. You can do `proxy_pass` + `proxy_protocol` within an NGINX stream, but this is typically not what you want, because that would break HTTP/2 and downgrade it to older protocol.

Make sure to read [UDS stack concepts](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/faster-web-server-stack-powered-by-unix-sockets-proxy). Specifically, it mentions why NGINX is bad choice for TLS termination in UDS setup:

> NGINX is not capable of forwarding PROXY protocol via http proxy module. It means that server { proxy_pass .... } TLS termination to a Varnish which listens on a PROXY protocol, will not work.

and

> nginx SSL stream + Varnish listening on PROXY protocol won’t support HTTP/2 because nginx SSL stream does not know how to negotiate ALPN proto.

Comment: Danila, спасибо большое for your explanation and your great blog post. So I know it's not working as I thought. I will keep it running with TCP for the time being and think about replacing nginx with hitch.

Comment: are you sure proxy_pass can't work with the proxy_protocol directive? http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol

Comment: @GuillaumeQuintard I am sure. You have given the link to stream module documentation. That means you can use `proxy_protocol` within `stream {}` context, but not within `http {}` context. When you refer to `proxy_pass`, you mostly mean the one within `http {}` context. I will update my answer for better clarity.